# CSV, Excel, PDF Report Generator for Mysql, .net 4.0

Tags: c#, mysql

I am in a strange juncture, where I need to generate reports in Excel, PDF and CSV formats.

I got it working for CSV format. but have no clue on how to generate Excel and PDF reports.

I am sure I dont have to re-invent the wheel to do all this stuff.

I can not use SSRS etc, as they are only for SQL Server.

Could some one please suggest a good reporting tool for Mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You can use open source [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/), а wrapper around OpenXML to conveniently generate xlsx files - i.e. Office 2007+ format Excel files. Can't help with PDF, but you can search [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/) for it too.